# Dual screen resolution - Startup problem

Tags: release-juno, graphic-drivers, resolution

Very new linux user here (3 days experience).

I have 2 screens, that i have setup properly, not without having to fiddle with the little visual tool provided by default with elementary OS (screen positioning can have a tendency to go all over the place).
They have 2 different resolutions.

On startup, my secondary screen won't start, as if with bad resolution. I then have to go into the tool (which displays the right resolution - super weird), then take a lower one, apply, and go back to the right resolution, which works (and still, i have to fiddle a bit with the positioning of the screen for some reason).

**Graphics Card:** NVIDIA GK104 [GeForce GTX 760 OEM] Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 ) drivers: nouveau (unloaded: modesetting,fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz, 2560x1440@59.95hz OpenGL: renderer: NVE4 version: 4.3 Mesa 19.0.8

Hope that it will be a good enough description, i am really just getting started ^^.

Comment: What hardware do you have, and what drivers?

Comment: Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA GK104 [GeForce GTX 760 OEM]
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 ) drivers: nouveau (unloaded: modesetting,fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz, 2560x1440@59.95hz
           OpenGL: renderer: NVE4 version: 4.3 Mesa 19.0.8

Comment: I'd try installing some of the recent Nvidia proprietary driver: sudo apt install nvidia-driver-430

Comment: This caused complete mayhem :P. Basically, my screens are no longer recognized :(.
It's actually impossible to pick another driver in the manager. As soon as i try to apply one, it reverts to another.. so freaky..